# The resource cannot be found. Description: HTTP 404. . AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating a angular app that is fetching product data from asp.net webapi. I have tested the asp.net webapi and its returning the data correctly. However i am getting an Resource cannot be found when the product.chtml page is loaded. I have checked for all the references made in the html file and the paths seems correct.

Please do let me know what the issue could be

**app.js**

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    var app = angular.module("productManagement", ["common.services"]);

}());
```

**productController.js**

```
(function () {

    "use strict";
    angular
        .module("productManagement")
       .controller("ProductController", ["productFactoryService", ProductController]);

    function ProductController(productFactoryService) {
        var vm = this;

        vm.productData = null;

        productFactoryService.GetAllRecords()
        .then(function (d)
        {
            vm.productData = d.data;
        },
        function () {
            alert('Error Occured !!!'); // Failed
        });

    }
}());
```

**common.services.js**

```
(function () {
    "use strict";

    angular
    .module("common.services", ["$http"]);


}());
```

**productFactory.js**

```
(function () {

    "use strict";

    angular
        .module("common.services")
        .factory("productFactoryService", ["$http", productFactoryService]);

    function productFactoryService($http)
    {

        var fac = {};
        fac.GetAllRecords = function () {
            return $http.get('api/Product/GetAllProducts');
        };
        return fac;

    }
}());
```

**Product.cshtml**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Product";
}

@section scripts{

    <script src="bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
     @*<script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.min.js"></script>*@

    <script src="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="App/app.js"></script>
    <script src="config.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Common/services/common.services.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Common/services/productFactory.js"></script>
    <script src="~/App/Product/productController.js"></script>

}

<div ng-app="productManagement" id="">
    <div ng-controller="ProductController">
        <h2>AngularJS CRUD operations with MVC5</h2>

        <h3>List of Products</h3>

        <table ng-cloak>

            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th style="display:none">Id</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Category</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Actions</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="items in vm.productData">
                    <td hidden="hidden">Id</td>
                    <td>{{item.ProductName}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.Cost}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.Price}}</td>
                    <td>{{item.Category}}</td>

                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Which ressource cannot be found? Is it `api/Product/GetAllProducts`?

Comment: Thats what i dont undertand. I dont think it is api as i had commented the api call but still got the error

Comment: You can see in the console what gives you the 404 error, it could be everything.

Comment: This is all i see in the console window http://localhost:23178/Views/Home/Product.cshtml Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: It seems like you cant even find Product.cshtml. Can you even get it to say Hello World?

Comment: You are correct. If I remove everything from the product.cshtml page and type hello world , it gives me the same error. If I run it in firefox , i get the same error, I even tried executing another controller method same error. Dont know whats happening. It was workingf fine until i added the service code. Has it got to do anything with $http dependency

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135895/discussion-between-tom-and-anders-vestergaard).